# How to process <input type="file" name="test1[f]" /> in PHP?

Tags: php, http, file, form-submit

`var_dump($_FILES)` gives the following:

```
array
  'test1' => 
    array
      'name' => 
        array
          'f' => string 'ntuser.dat.LOG' (length=14)
      'type' => 
        array
          'f' => string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)
      'tmp_name' => 
        array
          'f' => string 'D:\wamp\tmp\php223.tmp' (length=22)
      'error' => 
        array
          'f' => int 0
      'size' => 
        array
          'f' => int 0
```

Why is http designed this way?How can I process the array efficiently(sometimes means no looping?) so I can get the file by `$_FILES['test1']['f']`?

Answer (score 4):

I guess `input` fields with type `file` are not meant to be used with array like names.
Use

```
 <input type="file" name="test1_f" />
```

instead and access with `$_FILES['test1_f']`.

Otherwise you cannot access the single attributes of the file without looping.

Maybe you can show us how you create the input elements and how you want to process the `$_FILES` array in order to provide a better solution.

**Update:**
I have to redraw my statement partially. [As described here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), PHP supports [HTML array feature](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) also for files. But the point with this is, that the files on the server side should be processed as a whole.
They also provide a nice example how too deal with, maybe it helps you:

```
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "data/$name");
    }
}
```

If you want to have access to a single file, then you just use the wrong approach.

Comment: +1 You could reshuffle the array somehow but I would go with this suggestion - way easier.

Comment: yeah, so one can just foreach over $_FILES. very handy

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be pretty straightforward:

```
$filepath = $_FILES["test1"]["tmp_name"]["f"];
```